# Why doesn't the MBRS1100 Schottky diode have an exponential I/V characteristic?

Tags: diodes, datasheet

I have encountered the Schottky diode [MBRS1100](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/mbrs1100t3-d.pdf) by OnSemi, and I had a look at the datasheet. I scrolled down to check the I/V characteristic. I attached it here.

[image]

As you can see the relation does not follow an exponential curve, but maybe this is not the I/V characteristic of the diode, but of something else. Can you help me clarify this?

Comment: It does. The Y axis is logarithmic.

Comment: @Justme Since the Y axis is logarithmic, if the diode had a perfectly exponential I/V characteristic, then the curves on the plot would look like straight lines.

Comment: @TannerSwett No, because the Y axis is logarithmic but with base 10. The characteristic is exponential with base "e".

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, because taking the log base 10 is the same thing as taking the log base *e* and then dividing by ln 10. An exponential function plotted with a logarithmic scale will look like a straight line regardless of the base of the exponentiation and the logarithm.

Answer (score 7):

There are three components to the VI curve of a typical Schottky diode:

- Low currents: dominated by the Shockley equation. At very low voltages, current flow is dominated by the "-1" term (not visible on the above plot).  At modest voltages, by the exponential term (hence the largely linear (on the log plot) shape of the curve plotted).
- Medium to high currents: dominated by internal resistance, some of which comes from the derivative of the Shockley equation, but also from device design, as bulk semiconductor for example has significant resistance.
- High currents (surge conditions, typically): a PN guard ring, around or integrated with the Schottky structure, becomes forward-biased. This has a higher voltage drop to begin with (~0.7 V compared to the ~0.4 V or whatever of the Schottky junction alone), but can have much lower resistance (in particular, the generation of minority carriers causes conductivity modulation, which is to say, the resistance gets lower as current goes up -- even through the bulk semiconductor, as charge carriers diffuse some way into the bulk itself).

I'm not sure if that last point is unique; it's been long enough since semiconductor class that I can't remember if that applies to the Schottky junction as well. (If nothing else, the metal is an essentially unlimited source of electrons, but never of holes. But is that enough for conductivity modulation? I forget.)

Also, note that the last item (PN guard ring) might not be present on all diodes. Hence the "typical" specifier at the top. Most commercial parts do (MBRS1100 included), and the PN junction can also be tuned for reliable (or, better at least) avalanche breakdown, providing ESD immunity and some robustness to (in-circuit) surges or other extremes. So, you'll sometimes see avalanche energy specs on Schottky diodes, for this reason.

For this particular diode, the PN forward-bias I think is not visible over the scale plotted, or not significant compared to the second effect (resistance). Note that resistance has a proportional drop (V = I*R) so, when plotted on log axes, has a log(x) shape to it. Hence the curve bends to the right.

There are types that have the PN guard ring forward-bias evident; typically SiC Schottky do, in part because the bulk resistivity is much higher, so the difference in diode drops (also larger due to the wide bandgap) is more pronounced. This leads to a double-humped sort of curve. Again, Si Schottky may simply not show a double-humped curve, for various reasons (like the humps being too close together, or resistance dominating regardless).

Comment: For very high pulsed current (if possible), it should be a 'resistor' ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Well, yeah; more to the point -- or, to put it another way: the Thevenin equivalent will have a higher voltage and lower resistance, in the case of the PN guard ring, than without; but by how much, may not be easy to see from curves given. Put still another way: the 3rd item can be considered optional (whether because of perceptibility, or actual omission).

Comment: Reporting the characteristic in ( linear, linear) graph shoul help to measure easily this "resistor".

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't the MBRS1100 Schottky diode have an exponential I/V characteristic?

**Because theory is not reality.** Some parameters are not taken into account.
And one, for example, is the resistance (20 mΩ) "added" to the diode for the wiring.

For your information ... and a picture for "best" comparison ...
Here is a simulation (and mathematics calculus, Shockley diode equation, or
"Ebers-Moll" equation simplified ...)

Made with "interactive" capabilities of simulator, [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm).
You can see the approximation made.

**NB: note that MBRS1100 is a only 1 A - 100 V, although characteristics is drawn until 20 A ...**
Drawing with linear scales makes easy the "evaluation" of the "serial" ohmic resistor of the "wiring" (and some other effect").

Green curves: simulated at 3 temperatures = 25, 75, 125 °C,
Red curve: theoretical simulation with serial rs,
Blue curve: "true" exponential curve.

[image]